# argparse: Required add_mutually_exclusive_group parameters list as optional?

Tags: python, argparse, mutual-exclusion

I know that [argparse](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html) describes in its [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#required) that parameters starting with `-` or `--` are considered optional:

> In general, the argparse module assumes that flags like `-f` and `--bar` indicate optional arguments, which can always be omitted at the command line.

No matter if you define parameters as required or not, they will show up under "**optional arguments**" in argparse's help output:

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('--required_argument', action='store_true',  required=True)
parser.add_argument('--optional_argument', action='store_false', required=False)
parser.add_argument('positional_argument')
args = parser.parse_args()
```

This results in the following help output:

```
usage: demo.py [-h] --required_argument [--optional_argument] positional_argument

positional arguments:
  positional_argument

optional arguments:
  -h, --help           show this help message and exit
  --required_argument
  --optional_argument
```

As you might notice, no matter if the arguments starting with `-` or `--` are defined to be required or not, they are listed under "**optional arguments**". Only those square brackets in the "usage"-line indicate if it can be omitted or not.

I already know there is a workaround for that by using [add_argument_group()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#argparse.ArgumentParser.add_argument_group) like this:

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
group1 = parser.add_argument_group(title='required arguments')
group1.add_argument('--required_argument', action='store_true',  required=True)
parser.add_argument('--optional_argument', action='store_false', required=False)
parser.add_argument('positional_argument')
args = parser.parse_args()
```

```
usage: demo.py [-h] --required_argument [--optional_argument] positional_argument

positional arguments:
  positional_argument

optional arguments:
  -h, --help           show this help message and exit
  --optional_argument

required arguments:
  --required_argument
```

But how to achieve a similar thing in case you have mutually exclusive arguments?
Let's assume you need to provide one of two arguments, but not both at the same time. I know, there are better options like in this example, but for the sake of it: When you need the user to use either `--enable` or `--disable`: One needs to be provided, but both do not make sense.

If this is implemented like this, I do not know of a way to make it not end up under "**optional arguments**", since [add_mutually_exclusive_group()](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/argparse.html#argparse.ArgumentParser.add_mutually_exclusive_group) is lacking support for the "title" and "description" arguments of [add_argument_group()](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/argparse.html#argparse.ArgumentParser.add_argument_group):

> Note that currently mutually exclusive argument groups do not support the title and description arguments of [add_argument_group()](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/argparse.html#argparse.ArgumentParser.add_argument_group).

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
group1 = parser.add_mutually_exclusive_group(required=True)
group1.add_argument('--enable',  action='store_true',  help='Enable something')
group1.add_argument('--disable', action='store_false', help='Disable something')
args = parser.parse_args()
```

```
usage: demo.py [-h] (--enable | --disable)

optional arguments:
  -h, --help  show this help message and exit
  --enable    Enable something
  --disable   Disable something
```

So, anybody knows a solution with [argparse](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html) or is this a showstopper request and one must switch to something else like [click](https://click.palletsprojects.com/en/master/)?

Comment: You can define a mutually exclusive group inside an argument group.  In general groups aren't designed for nesting, but this particular combination does work, and is useful.

Comment: There are two default argument groups, one labeled `positional` the other `optional`.       The names reflect historical usage, and how they are processed (not the value of the `required` parameter).  The use of 'options' or 'optionals' goes back to `unix` `getopt` parsers.  I prefer the term `flagged`.

Answer (score 3):

You can create group and rearrange the optional arguments and required arguments for clean look

```py
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
optional = parser._action_groups.pop() #removes the optional arguments section
group1 = parser.add_argument_group("Required arguments")
group1 = group1.add_mutually_exclusive_group(required=True)
group1.add_argument('--enable',  action='store_true',  help='Enable something')
group1.add_argument('--disable', action='store_false', help='Disable something')
parser._action_groups.append(optional) # add optional arguments section again
args = parser.parse_args()
```

Output:

```
usage: argparse test.py [-h] (--enable | --disable)

Required arguments:
  --enable    Enable something
  --disable   Disable something

optional arguments:
  -h, --help  show this help message and exit
```

Answer (score 2):

Heed the note on the [`required` parameter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#required):

> **Note**: Required options are generally considered bad form because users expect *options* to be *optional*, and thus they should be avoided when possible.

So don't use required options; instead use positional arguments with `choices` or a sub-parser. Here's an example with positionals, which you'll notice is much simpler:

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(prog='demo.py')
parser.add_argument('action', choices=['enable', 'disable'], help='Action to take')

parser.print_help()

for arg in ['enable', 'disable', 'rotate']:
    print()
    print(parser.parse_args([arg]))
```

Output:

```
usage: demo.py [-h] {enable,disable}

positional arguments:
  {enable,disable}  Action to take

optional arguments:
  -h, --help        show this help message and exit

Namespace(action='enable')

Namespace(action='disable')

usage: demo.py [-h] {enable,disable}
demo.py: error: argument action: invalid choice: 'rotate' (choose from 'enable', 'disable')
```